# clusterssh: some key combinations are not passed to terminals

Tags: cluster-ssh

Normally when I have my text editor open in terminal, I use the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to move to the end of the file

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does not work when I am in the "main cssh input field", (ie when i am typing in multiple terminals). But if I select one of the open terminals directly, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> works.

So I assume, when I use it in the main input field, it gets "eaten".

Ideally, I would like `cssh` to pass all key combination to the terminals.
I don't need `cssh` to use its own key shortcuts.

Is there somewhere where I can configure / disable key shortcuts used by `cssh`, so that all are passed to terminals ?

Another problem is, when I press <kbd>F10</kbd>, it is not passed to the terminals, but opens the menu of `cssh`. This is pure evil. The `cssh` window already has menu, where I can click with mouse and select items. Who needs to sacrifice <kbd>F10</kbd>, for such stupid thing?

Is it possible to disable **all** keys in cssh, so that all are passed to the terminals ?

Comment: Generally speaking, terminals don't do anything interesting with key combinations like that (control+K **or** control+V, yes, but not all three at the same time).

Comment: Do you mean Ctl-k followed by v?

Comment: @Barmar - yes, Ctl-k followed by v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I unserstood it correctly you want to disable all shorctus for the `cssh`.  This could be done by disabling it in the configuration file.

In your `/etc/csshrc & $HOME/.csshrc` you need to configure it to:

```
   use_hotkeys = no
       Setting to anything other than "yes" will disable all hotkeys.
```

The source of the information were the [FreeBSD man pages for cssh](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cssh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%207.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&format=html)

**Edit - adding more options**

You can try to leave these options empty - don't assign it any default key combination:

```
   key_addhost = Control-plus
       Default key sequence to open AddHost menu.  See below notes on
       shortcuts.

   key_clientname = Alt-n
       Default key sequence to send cssh client names to client.  See
       below notes on shortcuts.

   key_paste = Control-v
       Default key sequence to paste text into the console window.
       See below notes on shortcuts.

   key_quit = Control-q
       Default key sequence to quit the program (will terminate all
       open windows).  See below notes on shortcuts.

   key_retilehosts = Alt-r
       Default key sequence to retile host windows.  See below notes
       on shortcuts.

   mouse_paste = Button-2 (middle mouse button)
       Default key sequence to paste text into the console window us-
       ing the mouse.  See below notes on shortcuts.
```

**Edit - for future readers**  The issue appeared to be in the GUI env itself - which was *OpenBox*.  You need to watch out if the settings of the environment do not colide with the cssh ones.

Comment: Thanks. I changed to `use_hotkeys=no`, but I see no effect. The problem is still same.

Comment: as an example: I launch several terminals with `cssh`, connecting to remote servers. I start `mc` and then exit with `F10`. The `F10` worked, in that it exited `mc`, but after that, the `cssh` menu is activated, and if I press enter, it does not appear in the terminals. instead it opens the file menu in the `cssh` menu.

Comment: @400theCat are you sure your settings does not get overwritten by the global settings?

Comment: I don't see any global settings. besides, user settings should always take precedence, if it exists. can `use_hotkeys` be provided as commandline parameter? I can try that, to be sure.

Comment: @400theCat you are right, they should, but we know software, it is full of bugs :).  I'll update the answer with more options that could influence it.

Comment: I have pasted my complete config from ~/.clusterssh/config: https://justpaste.it/6vsv8

Comment: @400theCat you can't have command line parameter, it can be influence only by the configuration file.

Comment: @400theCat I have create a chat room so we could discuss it futher - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109561/room-for-tukan-and-400-the-cat